# Add Equal to symbol in link inside email body when email is delivered in outlook inbox mail send by php mail

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmailer

I am sending mail using php mailer mail working fine with gmail but when i am sending it to another host email in outlook it add = symbol in link, body contain the link this email is used for forgot password.

this is the normal link
    http://support.domain.com/login/resetpw/a3ad3e46c045d98dba19a94dc8a9e4329dcab251/7

It is good when it is coming in gmail inbox

When it comes in outlook it will become like this

```
http://support.domain.com/login/**=**esetpw/a3ad3e46c045d98dba19a94dc8a9e4329dcab251/7
```

when i tried to short the url position of the = is changed.

Comment: Interesting, it also changes the domain

Comment: @kerbholz Sorry, I write different domain mistakenly.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook is known to be buggy in its handling of message bodies using a quoted-printable transfer encoding, which is what this sounds like. Make sure you're using [the latest version of PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) which contains workarounds for that.